# How can I make .addEventListener only execute functions if all conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, time, addeventlistener

```
if (!date.value && !startTime.value && !endTime.value) {
    [startTime, endTime, date].forEach(item => {
        {
            item.addEventListener("change", function () {

                    console.log(`${date.value}` + "T" + `${startTime.value}` + ":00" + "Z" + ","
                        + `${date.value}` + "T" + `${endTime.value}` + ":00" + "Z"
                    );

                }
            )
        }
    })
}
```

In the Code above I only want the console.log to execute when all conditions
`if (!date.value && !startTime.value && !endTime.value)`are fullfilled. Now it always console.logs a value if only one condition is met.
When I check for these values:

```
console.log(startTime.value);
console.log(endTime.value);
console.log(date.value);
```

The console just shows me an empty line. So their default values should be `""`, right?
Does someone know why the function gets executed when only one value is changed?

Comment: _“Does someone know why the function gets executed when only one value is changed?”_ - because that condition gets checked once, _before_ you are even adding the event handlers. After that, the event handlers _are_ added to the elements in question - so they execute your callback function, every time the value of one of those fields get changed by the user - doesn’t matter _into_ what, just that they _do_ get changed.

Comment: Your code says : 1. Check some condition. If the condition is met, 2. Attach click handlers everywhere. 3. On click, console.log. So that's exactly what's happening, because the logic is flawed. The code should say : 1. Attach all click handlers. 2. On click, check if the condition is met, and if it is, 3. console.log.

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding listeners when you don't need to. Initially add the listeners to the inputs, and then have a function to handle what happens.

```js
// Grab the inputs
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

// Add a listener to each - note that depending on the number of
// inputs you have you might want to switch to event delegation
// https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/
[...inputs].forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);
});

function handleChange(e) {

  // Now just check to see if any of the inputs are empty
  const allAreEmpty = [...inputs].every(input => {
    return input.value === '';
  });

  // And return an answer only when none of the
  // inputs are empty
  if (allAreEmpty) console.log(1);

}
```

```html
<input id="date" />
<input id="startTime" />
<input id="endTime" />
```

Additional documentation

- [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!
I found a solution looking like this:

```js
 //checking for change of all values. Then console.log values on change and executing request if busy.
 [...inputs].forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('change', function () {
                if (date.value !== "" && startTime.value !== "" && endTime.value !== ""
                ) {
                    console.log(`"${date.value}T${startTime.value}:00Z",
                    "${date.value}T${endTime.value}:00Z"`);
                    freeRequest.execute(function (resp) {
                        console.log(resp);
                    })

                } else {
                    console.log("change date pls")
                }
            }
        )
    }
 )
```